# Matlab database explorer: Error using cursor/fetch (line 363) Java exception occurred: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: matlab, jdbc

I used the database explorer package to generate the following code.

```
function r = physicians()

%Set preferences with setdbprefs.
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat', 'cellarray');
setdbprefs('NullNumberRead', 'NaN');
setdbprefs('NullStringRead', 'null');


%Make connection to database.  Note that the password has been omitted.
%Using JDBC driver.
conn = database('censored', 'censored', '', 'Vendor', 'ORACLE', 'Server', 'cesnored', 'PortNumber', censored, 'DriverType', 'thin');

%Read data from database.
curs = exec(conn, ['SELECT  RECIPIENT.RECIPIENT_ID'...
    ' , RECIPIENT.FNAME'...
    ' , RECIPIENT.LNAME'...
    ' , RECIPIENT.LANGUAGE'...
    ' , RECIPIENT.PHONE'...
    ' , RECIPIENT.FAX'...
    ' , RECIPIENT.CITY'...
    ' , RECIPIENT.POSTAL_CODE'...
    ' FROM  "STI".RECIPIENT ']);

curs = fetch(curs);
close(curs);

%Assign data to output variable
r = curs.Data;

%Close database connection.
close(conn);

%Clear variables
clear curs conn
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using cursor/fetch (line 363)
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Vector.grow(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Vector.ensureCapacityHelper(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Vector.addElement(Unknown Source)

at com.mathworks.toolbox.database.fetchTheData.dataFetch(fetchTheData.java:763)


Error in physicians (line 24)
curs = fetch(curs);
```

However, when I just import directly using the tool, I don't get an error like this. I'm guessing I need to limit the amount of RAM being used, but I don't really know how.

Comment: The error message in the title and in your question don't match, what is the right message?

Comment: Oops. The one in the post is correct. I forgot to adjust the title.

Comment: Corrected it, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You may try to increase the heap size, open the documentation with the `doc` command and search for "Java Heap Memory Preferences" (Use the local version to get the correct information for your Matlab version)

Comment: Is there any way to get around the heap size limitations? I can do things in batches?

Why would this fail in the script but work when I just hit the button?

Comment: Bside Increasing the Java Heap, import in batches, i.e. not all rows at once. Also, avoiding `'DataReturnFormat', 'cellarray'` helps too. Or import a column at a time.